# Nokogiri and tables

Tags: ruby, parsing, nokogiri

Am parsing a web page with a standard structure as follows:

```
<html>
  <body>
     <table>
        <tbody>
           <tr class="active">
             <td>name1</td>
             <td>name2</td>
             <td>name3</td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

For the life of me, I can't access the 'tbody' or 'tr' elements.

```
response = open('http://my_url')
node = Nokogiri::HTML(response).css('table')
puts node
```

Returns

```
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x8294c08c name="table" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x8294c014 name="id" value="beta-users">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x82953bc0 "\n">]>
```

I have tried various tricks but can't seem to dig deeper down to a lower-level child than 'table'.

At best, I can get to the lowest-level Text object by using

```
node.children
```

but

```
node.children.text
```

returns "\n".

Despite searching for some hours am none the wiser how to sort it out. Any thoughts?

Comment: Running your code with the current html works as expected - I get: `"\n`...`name1\n             name2\n             name3\n`...`"`

Comment: What about the Nokogiri::XML elements returned. Does that shed any light? The html is paraphrased from a site, not the actual html I am parsing.

Comment: From the `Nokogiri::XML` elements, it looks like the table is really empty - are you sure the HTML you are getting is well formed? Browsers can be very lenient when parsing HTML, and the nokogiri engine might be more strict...

Comment: aha, so this could be the problem. Is there any way to check what is being returned. It is true that the html site I am scraping is an internal admin site (for my company)... so do I need to tell the backend dev to do anything in particular to make it scrapable?

Comment: perhaps this could be a case for selenium web browser, as there is a slight delay while the server loads the data in the site....

Comment: You need to take the textual response, and try to find how it is compromised, so you'd know how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

There is a non-closed class value in your sample, it should be:

```
<html>
  <body>
     <table>
        <tbody>
           <tr class="active">
             <td>name1</td>
             <td>name2</td>
             <td>name3</td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

After correcting this, you can:

```
node = Nokogiri::HTML(response).css('table tbody tr td')
node.each {|child| puts child.text}
name1
name2
name3
```

Comment: That was a typo on my behalf - edited now. Still no joy.

Comment: So, what's the exact problem? I showed how to reach `<td>` elements

Comment: It doesn't work with reference to the output returned as XML above. I think the answer is somewhere in here: #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x8294c08c name="table" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x8294c014 name="id" value="beta-users">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x82953bc0 "\n">]>

Comment: Can you post the exact XML you are trying to parse? I can't see any id="beta-users" in the example you posted, so it is hard to guess where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks @grych am trying out now watir and watir-nokogiri as nokogiri is grabbing the html before the server responds, hence the empty element